# MongoDB root user can't access config database

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to set up backups on a mongoDB instance (version 4.4) using `mongodump`. That requires access to the `config` database and my mongo user doesn't have that, despite being in the `root` role. (From my understanding of [the documentation on built-in roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#root), a user with the `root` role should be able to backup all databases on the instance.)

When I try to run `mongodump`, I get this error:

```
root@mongo-db1:/srv/mongo# mongodump --username=rcroot --password="secret" --out=/var/backups/20200925
2020-09-26T05:40:20.138+0000    Failed: error counting config.system.indexBuilds: not authorized on config to execute command { count: "system.indexBuilds", query: {}, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "config" }
```

So apparently my user doesn't have access to `config`. Here's my user:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.getUser("rcroot")
{
        "_id" : "admin.rcroot",
        "userId" : UUID("81fc86ff-6d12-4d23-83ab-7fc2591516a2"),
        "user" : "rcroot",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
```

I get similar errors to the above if I log in to the `mongo` shell with my root user and try to access anything in the `config` database. I do have authentication enabled, as I am starting `mongod` with the `--auth` flag:

```
mongod --auth --replSet rs0 --keyFile /data/db/keyfile --enableMajorityReadConcern false
```

So my question is: what do I need to do to grant this user true `root` access to all databases on my mongo instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by a version mismatch between the `mongodump` executable and the `mongod` server. (I was running `mongod` within a docker container, and I was trying to do backups from the host outside the container which had a different version of the tools installed.)

When I switched to the `mongodump` version that shipped with the server version, it worked fine.